# bmesh.ops method to get Loose vertices / edges and delete from that list?

Tags: python

I read all the api about bmesh.ops, but not find and not have idea to get loose edge/vertices , someone knows something about it, I don't even find examples to `get` and then `delete` with method `bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom, context`)
Equivalent with ops (Slow if have many object) `bpy.ops.mesh.delete_loose()`

```
meshes = set(o.data for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH')
bm = bmesh.new()

for m in meshes:

    bm.from_mesh(m)
    ####get list of loose vertices/edge?
    ####delete vertices?
    bm.to_mesh(m)
    m.update()
    bm.clear()
```

example about loose edges:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Verts with no linked faces**

Possibly easiest here is to look for verts with no linked faces. *ie they make no part of any face*

```
import bpy
import bmesh
context = bpy.context

meshes = set(o.data for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH')
bm = bmesh.new()

for m in meshes:

    bm.from_mesh(m)
    # verts with no linked faces
    verts = [v for v in bm.verts if not v.link_faces]

    print(f"{m.name}: removed {len(verts)} verts")
    # equiv of bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=verts, context='VERTS')
    for v in verts:
        bm.verts.remove(v)

    bm.to_mesh(m)
    m.update()
    bm.clear()
```

Comment: Work fine. According to you to simulate "Delete loose" vertex, edge, face this method can be fine?